# Set location to image using paintComponent

Tags: java, swing

I have the next code:

```
public class GalleryPrinter extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public GalleryPrinter() {

    }

    public GalleryPrinter(LinkedList<String> paths) {

        for(int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++ ) {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File(paths.get(i)));


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GalleryPrinter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //g.drawImage(image, 25, 25, this); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 140, 200, this);
    }

}
```

But is printing all the images in the same place, defined here:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 140, 200, this);
```

How I can make this position dynamic? Something like:
If is the first image
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 140, 200 * index, this);
To create a vertical image gallery.

Someone can help me with that?

Comment: Create an ArrayList to contain all your images. Then in the paintComponent() method your iterate through the ArrayList. As you paint each image you would get the height of the image and then adjust the value of "y" when you paint the next image.

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass parameters to paintComponent to get the index to calculate the "y" @camickr

Comment: You don't pass parameters. The ArrayList is an instance variable of the class the same way your "image" variable is an instance variable. The difference is you no longer need the "image" variable because all the images will be added to the ArrayList in your for loop.